# Dismiss UIActivityViewController after item pressed Swift

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to dismiss the UIActivityViewController after the user successfully shares the payload.

The sharing is occurring over airdrop

For instance, User shares object over airdrop, activity view controller exits.

I've tried using ActivityViewControllers completion handlers but I seem to only get feedback after the user exits. Other than that I have no idea what to do.

Here my code.

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController()
activityItems: ["Send Payload!", url!],
applicationActivities: nil)

activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {(activityType: UIActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems:[Any]?, error: Error?) in
    //...
    print(completed)
}
```

Comment: You should share your code, which approaches you have tried so far, where specifically you're stuck right now. Don't expect people to do all the work for you.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I updated my question but I really don't know that much to move forward.

Comment: I am using ActivityViewController in quite a few places, and I have zero code to control dismissal of it. After the user choses their action, it appears to auto dismiss. Is there more info on your specific use case?

Comment: I just realized that my case only applies to airdrop.

Comment: Please describe behaviour after you press airdrop button. Does `completionWithItemsHandler` get called? If yes, what is the printed value of `completed`?

Comment: It does not get called, only once the user clicks cancel/done

Comment: Looks like it's a system behavior, check Photos app, it also does not dismiss activity sheet after something is air-dropped, allowing user to select other items and airdrop them at the same activity. Consider to change your use-case.